# Определение наличия символов в строке

Tags: алгоритм, php

Подскажите как проверить переменную на наличие определенных символов? Например, русских букв, знаков препинания и тд. Нужно для логинов.

Comment: @zhekonya Уважаемый участник, у Вас 0% принятых ответов, не забывайте принимать ответы, если они реально отвечают на вопросы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if( preg_match('/[а-я\,\.]/ui', $str) ){ ... }
```

И не надо никаких iconv

Comment: Тут не все русские буквы.

Answer (score 2):

Проще проверить на наличие несоответствующих символов:
`if(preg_match('/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/', $_POST['login'])){...} // если есть не латинская буква и не цифра`

Ну а если нужно проверить наличие символов в строке, то можно сделать так:
`if(preg_match('/[0-9]/', $_POST['login'])){...} // если есть хотя бы одна цифра`

Answer (score 1):

Что бы прег матчем на русские буквы проверить, переведи строку сначала в кириллицу (если конечно, она не в ней.)

```
iconv("utf-8","windows-1251",$str);// Из утф-8 в кирилицу перевели
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы неправильно поставили себе задачу. Вам не нужно искать неверные символы в строке, лучше проверить всю строку на соответствие определенному паттерну, это решит вашу проблему (а так же другие, которые у вас могут возникнуть в случае изменения алгоритма проверки):

- "^w{6,8}$" - для любых букв и чисел и знака подчеркивания
- "^[A-Za-zd_]{6,8}$" - для английскик букв и чисел и знака подчеркивания

[полезная ссылка](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php#match)

Answer (score 0):

1. Насчёт утф8: не нужно никаких iconv() если вы всё время в 1 кодировке трудитесь и всё в ней. *НО* нужно указать setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.utf-8'). Иначе намаетесь с конвертацией кодировок.
2. Остальное - регулярными выражениями.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать такой вариант:

```
//строка с допустимыми символами
$symbol = 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm._-QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM0123456789';
     if( strlen($user_pass) == strspn($user_pass,$symbol)){
     //запрещённых символов нет...
     }
```

с кодировкой проблем не возникает.